# Can a single document fragment be used several times

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know if a single document fragment can be used to insert several fragment in the DOM, or do I have to create new ones for each element I want to insert.

Can I do the example below:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    section = document.createElement('section'),
    header = document.createElement('header'),
    divFrag = frag.appendChild(div),
    sectionFrag = frag.appendChild(section),
    headFrag = frag.appendChild(header);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note about your code: `appendChild` returns the DOM element inserted, so:

```
divFrag = frag.appendChild(div)
```

will return `div`. i.e. `div === divFrag`.

To answer your question, you can re-use a document fragment.

If, for example, you wanted to append all elements to the `<body>`, you could do it like so:

```
frag.appendChild(div);
frag.appendChild(section);
frag.appendChild(header);

document.body.appendChild(frag); // append all three elems at once to the body

// frag is now an empty fragment, ready for re-use
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact same dom can't be reused if you need to set `id` attributes, since ids need to be unique.

You can use some sort of templating, from which you get custom dom fragments that are alike in structure but different with respect to values.

Answer (score 0):

No, that will give the same result as:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
div = document.createElement('div'),
section = document.createElement('section'),
header = document.createElement('header');

frag.appendChild(div);
frag.appendChild(section);
frag.appendChild(header);

var divFrag = div, sectionFrag = section, headFrag = header;
```

So, your fragment will end up with three elements, and the `divFrag`, `sectionFrag` and `headFrag` variables will not be fragments at all.